# How to use PutAsJsonAsync in .NET 4.72?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am planning to use HTTP PUT in a WPF .NET 4.7.2 application and before I get started I wanted to quickly test putting data using a console .NET 4.7.2 application but I am getting an error on   `var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/person", p).Result;`

Error:

> Error CS1061  'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'PutAsJsonAsync' and no accessible extension method 'PutAsJsonAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClassLibrary;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;

namespace HTTP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                person p = new person { name = "Sourav", surname = "Kayal" };
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1565/");
                var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/person", p).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.Write("Success");
                }
                else
                    Console.Write("Error");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is [explicitly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.putasjsonasync) to be available only from .NET 6 onwards, so the short answer for how you use it on .NET 4.7.2 is "you don't". You can, of course, implement equivalent functionality using what *is* available (serialize the contents yourself, use `.PutAsync`).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package and use it this way instead :

```csharp
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{     
    Person p = new Person { name = "Sourav", surname = "Kayal" };
    string jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(p);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1565/");
    var response = client.PutAsync("api/person", content).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) Console.Write("Success");
    else Console.Write("Error");
}
```

Here is the Microsoft documentation (.NET Framework 4.7.2) :
[HttpClient.PutAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Not sure the `System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.PutAsJsonAsync` method is available for .NET Framework 4.7.2...

Comment: I am getting a bad request code 400, How can I incorporate Content-Type gzip, deflate, br ?

Comment: You can add http request headers like this :
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");